# Body width isn’t 100% when browser window is under 400px wide

Tags: html, css

My HTML and body width isn’t 100% when the browser window is under 400px wide. However it works perfectly over 400px wide.

I’ve tried setting body and html to padding:0 and margin: 0 and a CSS reset * and well as border-box properties from solutions posted here which haven’t worked for me.

**Test website link**: https://louisefindlay23.github.io/

The orange background and content should extend to the whole page exactly as it does when the browser window is over 400px wide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Foundation ZURB image is too wide at that resolution. Give it (and your other images) the CSS rule of `max-width: 100%` to make it responsive and fit on that size screen.

E.g. `img {max-width:100%;}`